# Why is adOpenKeySet needed to bind an ADO recordset to Access object?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was trying to bind an ADO recordset to an Access object with the following code

```
rs.Open "select * from Table1", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

However, I get the following error on the last line of code

> the object you entered is not a valid recordset property
>   on the line

```
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

However, if I change the cursor property to `adOpenKeyset`, I do not get any error and the recordset object is set properly

Is this because Access object only supports Keyset type key?

Comment: Are you trying to set record source of a form?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have successfully done it but only with adOpenKeyset not with adOpenDynamic so I wanted to know why adOpenDynamic does not work

Comment: Well, I would not use recordset at all. I would simply set form RecordSource property with the SQL string. So, why are you using recordset?

Comment: This is how microsoft docs says to do it to bind a form to ADO recordset. I am not sure we can create an ADO found form by setting RecourdSource to SQL string.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/activex-data-objects/bind-a-form-to-an-ado-recordset

Comment: And what is the reason for this approach? Why not just set form RecordSource property in form design? However, sounds like you answered your own question.